# Working with ActiveRecord and columns with apostrophes

Tags: ruby, activerecord, activemodel

I have a database I cannot modify, and it contains column names that are... let's just say stupid. Most are fine, but a couple of them have an apostrophe in it. One is called "Spouse's Birthday".

I can connect to the DB fine using `establish_connection`, and I can even pull off a `Model.count`. But the moment I try `Model.find`, it fails with the following error:

```
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activemodel-5.2.2/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:380:in `module_eval': /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activemodel-5.2.2/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:381: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')' (SyntaxError)
...       define_method(:'Spouse's Birthday_before_type_cast') ...
...                               ^
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activemodel-5.2.2/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:382: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end-of-input
          attribute_before_type_cast("Spouse's Birthday", *args)
```

The error message is pretty straightforward; the apostrophe in the column name is ruining everything. I need a way to either escape that, or feed `establish_connection` something that can map the existing column names to the names I would prefer using.